# How to Hide TitleBar in Hololens UWP App

Tags: uwp, hololens

I'm able to manipulate/hide the titlebar in UWP apps for desktops with code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440438/how-to-hide-collapse-title-bar-in-a-uwp-app) answer:

```
ApplicationViewTitleBar formattableTitleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
formattableTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor   = Colors.Transparent;
CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar    = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar         = true;
```

but it doesn't work for the Hololens environment. I've searched the documentation but cannot seem to find a workaround.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to use the [StatusBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633864) class. Referencing this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gianlucb/2015/10/08/uwp-windows-10-app-titlebar-and-status-bar-customization/), I believe the following code should hide the StatusBar.

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
}
```